# How do I efficiently filter a data frame obtained by a two-column groupby operation to include just the max and min values of the second index?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame `df` that was obtained by performing a two-column groupby operation:

```
df = data.groupby(['letters', 'syllables']).size()
```

Here is the output of the first 11 rows of `df`:

```
                      0
letters syllables      
1       1            25
        3             1
2       1           188
        2            44
        3             1
        4             1
3       1          1304
        2           189
        3            89
        4             2
        5             3
```

I would like to filter `df` so that for each index in `letters`, only the max and min indices of `syllables` are shown, giving the following output:

```
                      0
letters syllables      
1       1            25
        3             1
2       1           188
        4             1
3       1          1304
        5             3
```

Even better would be to create a data frame like this:

```
                               0
letters statistic syllables     
1       min       1           25
        max       3            1
2       min       1          188
        max       4            1
3       min       1         1304
        max       5            3
```

The full data frame has 120 rows. I know I could do this with a loop, but I am trying to understand pandas operations better and would like to know how to do this more efficiently.

The sample data above can be imported from a csv file into a multi-level index data frame using the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=[0,1])
```

**Edit:** Here is the output of the code suggested by Erfan:

```
df = data.groupby(['letters', 'syllables']).agg({'letters' : 'size', 'syllables' : ['min', 'max']})
```

Output:

```
                  letters syllables    
                     size       min max
letters syllables                      
1       1              25         1   1
        3               1         3   3
2       1             188         1   1
        2              44         2   2
        3               1         3   3
        4               1         4   4
3       1            1304         1   1
        2             189         2   2
        3              89         3   3
        4               2         4   4
        5               3         5   5
```

Comment: I think you need:`df = data.groupby(['letters', 'syllables']).agg({'letters' : 'size', 'syllables' : ['min', 'max']})`, but cant be sure because we dont see the input dataframe

Comment: Thank you @Erfan. I've updated my question to show the results of your code suggestion. It is difficult to include a concise data sample that will generate the groupby output, but I can continue working on one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it separately then `concat` it back

```
s=data.groupby(['letters', 'syllables']).size().sort_values(0)
yourdf=pd.concat([s.groupby(level=0).head(1),s.groupby(level=0).tail(1)],keys=['min','max']).swaplevel(i=0,j=1).sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you! I can get exactly what I want by adding the following code: ``df = yourdf.swaplevel(i=0,j=1).sort_index()``